# Magento 2: Customize each item when adding several items to the cart

Tags: magento2, custom-options

There's a catering company that sells a sandwich. They will only take an order if the customer buys a minimum of 10. Each sandwich can be customized (turkey, ham, egg salad, ...).

Ideal customer interaction would be:

- Customer sees a single "sandwich" page
- They choose the quantity >= 10 (will not allow under 10. This is currently handled in Advanced Inventory >>  Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart)
- The customer chooses the type for each sandwich, before **or** after pressing Add To Cart

Is there a way that Magento 2 can handle this customer interaction, without writing a custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible but there will be some limitations.

You can add this feature using the **Customizable Options** feature available in the product section.

For Using that just go to the below location & customize it as you want.

> Magnto_Admin_Left_Side_Menu => Catalog => Products => Select Your Product
>   => Customizable Option Section => Add Option

**Benefits:**

- You can add as much options as you want
- You can set the prices also as per the customizable options something like `Add extra cheese => Yes = $5 / No = $0`
- You can increase the prices on % basis as well.
- You can provide both predefined options to choose or can take the user Inputs as well.

**Draw backs:**

- Options doesn't has the dependencies features i.e. you can't create such feature like if user chooses one option so it will show the other dependent option.

  E.g.: Option 1) Sandwich Type : 1) Normal 2) Grilled
  Now if customer chooses type grilled than it should show other
  option that is Option 2) Grilled with: 1) Oil 2) Butter 3) cheese etc.
- It will occupy so much space in the product section which sometimes spoiling the look & feel of the product page.
- So many options selection is annoying for the customers sometime.

But it is a good option to create your feature You can at-least try this because it is already available feature & easy to use & of-course free of charge. For how to use it you can search on google there are so many videos & tutorials available for the same. [Here is the one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5_o44hOA0c) it is created using the old version of Magento but don't worry it is working like same.

Comment: Yep, this would work great if I needed all 10 sandwiches to be "ham". It's a simple and powerful feature but I need the customer to choose EACH sandwich type and this won't handle it without the customer going back to this page and adding to cart for each type. Example: Add to cart 6 Ham Sandwiches, reload the product page and then add 4 Turkey Sandwiches. That's the ugly design I need to avoid. Also, I don't need dependencies though there are plugins available that can handle that very well.